# A converse of the Erdős-De Bruijn Theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics

For the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ of a simple, undirected graph, there is a ["compactness" theorem by Erdős and De Bruijn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)) stating that if an infinite graph $G$ has finite chromatic number, then there is a finite subgraph $G_0\subseteq G$ such that $\chi(G_0) = \chi(G)$.

A converse statement would be

> $(\text{S})$ Let $k>0$ be an integer. Whenever a graph $G$ has the property that every finite subgraph $G_0$ of $G$ can be colored with $k$ colors, then $G$ can be colored with $k$ colors.

Is $(\text{S})$ true?

Comment: Isn't $(S)$ the usual statement of the Erdös-De Bruijn theorem? From the second line in the wikipedia link: "It states that, when all finite subgraphs can be colored with $c$ colors, the same is true for the whole graph"

Comment: But even if you take the statement in the question, $(S)$ is an immediate corollary. Suppose $\chi(G_0)=k$ for every finite $G_0\subset G$. Obviously $\chi(G)\geq k$. But we can't have $\chi(G)>k$ because that would be witnessed by a finite subgraph.

Comment: This can be proven by applying compactness for 1st order logic, right?

Comment: @Monroe that's right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently yes. By googling, I found the assertion in [this 1951 paper of de Bruijn and Erdős](http://combinatorica.hu/~p_erdos/1951-01.pdf), and the first page contains several further references.